# How to convert this code in devexpress VCL for Delphi

Tags: c#, delphi, devexpress

Hello I want to convert this code into VCL Delphi:

```
    // Create an empty list.
ArrayList rows = new ArrayList();
// Add the selected rows to the list.
for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.SelectedRowsCount; i++) {
   if (gridView1.GetSelectedRows()[i] >= 0)
      rows.Add(gridView1.GetDataRow(gridView1.GetSelectedRows()[i]));
}
try {
   gridView1.BeginUpdate();
   for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count; i++) {
      DataRow row = rows[i] as DataRow;
      // Change the field value.
      row["Discontinued"] = true;                             
   }
}
finally {
   gridView1.EndUpdate();
}
```

I am trying to do the same but in VCL there is not SelectedRowsCount or GetSelectedRows where can I find thoughs?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code conversion service..

Comment: If someone is into VCL Will know how to convert this code. I can't find where in gridview are those methods

Comment: Does the component not come with documentation?

Comment: This looks lazy. We aren't here to convert code for you. Phrase the question to ask about the specific problem at hand, rather than asking us to convert code. Also, this code is wrong. The `try` must come **before** the resource is acquired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just procedure that do what are you finding:
Sender is your gridView1 and isConnected is the value for your column.

```
procedure TForm1.ChangeColumn(Sender: TcxCustomGridTableView; isConnected: boolean);
var i: integer; AColumn: TcxCustomGridTableItem;
begin
  if ((TcxGridDBTableView(Sender).Controller.SelectedRecordCount=0)
    or (TcxGridDBTableView(Sender).Controller.SelectedRecords[0] = nil))
  then exit;

  AColumn:= TcxGridDBTableView(Sender).GetColumnByFieldName('Discontinued');
  if AColumn = nil then exit;

  TcxGridDBTableView(Sender).DataController.BeginFullUpdate;
  try
    for i:= 0 to TcxGridDBTableView(Sender).Controller.SelectedRecordCount-1 do
    begin
        TcxGridDBTableView(Sender).Controller.SelectedRecords[i].Values[AColumn.index] := isConnected;
    end;

  finally
    TcxCustomGridTableView(Sender).DataController.EndFullUpdate;
  end;
end;
```